# Why does a squared border show up around my ColorBox "trigger", when i close the ColorBox window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colorbox

I am appyling [ColorBox](http://www.google.dk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDwQFjAA&url=http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/&ei=RkZjT8nYO8_DtAagpazIBQ&usg=AFQjCNHSPpOZQWojOKgApvPIJ0wYAOHHCw&sig2=FiaI1M4RlAMP-ZdZBQXu9g) on a link:

```
<a class="iframe cboxElement" href="/SmallSurvey/SmallSurvey/Introduction?refUrl=survey"><img class="qtips" helptext="Tryk hvis du har brug for hjælp" src="@Url.Content("~/Images/help-icon.PNG")" height=20px" style="border:none;" /></a>
```

The icon in the link looks normal before i click it. When i click it, colorbox opens a new window as it is supposed to. When i close this window, there is a border around my image.

Could this be because of colorbox? I am also running the [qTip](http://www.google.dk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/&ei=BUZjT9HvIc_0sga2j7HoBQ&usg=AFQjCNGhvf6twBZUaZ9AE8s74uiu_55Y1Q&sig2=Pn-ydb3i4w5b1r_0GnTXSw) plugin on the image, but i doubt that it is the reason.

[image]

Comment: Looks like the link just receives focus. Try adding the css rule outline: none to the link.

Answer (score 0):

Default: `returnFocus: true`

Updated:  `returnFocus: false`

If true, focus will be returned when Colorbox exits to the element it was launched from.

for more detail visit [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) website and read returnFocus Property.